# How do I add borders or images to my MapKit route paths?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, mapkit

In iOS 5, Apple updated the look of the routes in Maps.app. Now selected routes show a bright blue line with beveled/glossy effect, while unselected routes have a thin blue border. Below is an image what I mean.

So far in my own application, I've only been able to draw routes as a single color line. Is it possible to reproduce this effect with current APIs? If so, how would I go about doing it? Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

[image: Fancy routes in Maps.app in iOS 5]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing MKMapView Overlay like Google Maps Directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675081/drawing-mkmapview-overlay-like-google-maps-directions)