# Drawing MKMapView Overlay like Google Maps Directions

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mkmapview, mapkit, drawrect

iOS 5 changed the way the built-in Google Maps App draws routes:

[image: Apple's line]

I would now like to replicate the design of the route overlay in my own app but I am currently   only able to draw a plain blue line. I would like to add the 3D-effect with the gradient, borders and the glow. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Resulting in a rather ugly line:

[image: my line]

Thanks!

Update: The solution should work on iOS 4.0 and up.

Comment: Are you able to post the code you're using the draw the lines, currently?

Comment: @sudo rm -rf: I've added the drawing code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that @ChrisMiles is correct in that the segments are probably being drawn individually.  (I initially thought that this might have been doable using `CGPatternRef` but you don't have any access to the CTM or path endpoints inside the pattern drawing callback.)

With this in mind, here is an exceedingly crude, back-of-the-envelope example of how you might begin such an effort (filling the segments individually).  Note that:

- gradient colors are guessed
- end caps are nonexistent and will need to be separately implemented
- some aliasing artifacts remain
- not a great deal of attention was paid to performance

Hopefully this can get you started at least (and works through some of the analytic geometry).

```
-  (CGGradientRef)lineGradient
{
    static CGGradientRef gradient = NULL;
    if (gradient == NULL) {
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGColorRef white = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f
                                              alpha:0.7f] CGColor];
        CGColorRef blue = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f
                                           green:0.2f
                                            blue:1.f
                                           alpha:0.7f] CGColor];
        CGColorRef lightBlue = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.4f
                                                green:0.6f
                                                 blue:1.f
                                                alpha:0.7f] CGColor];
        CFMutableArrayRef colors = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                        8,
                                                        NULL);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, blue);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, blue);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, white);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, white);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, lightBlue);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, lightBlue);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, blue);
        CFArrayAppendValue(colors, blue);
        CGFloat locations[8] = {0.f, 0.08f, 0.14f, 0.21f, 0.29f, 0.86f, 0.93f, 1.f};
        gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,
                                              colors,
                                              locations);
        CFRelease(colors);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    }
    return gradient;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);

    // Fill background color
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    // Build a path
    CGFloat strokeWidth = 10.f;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);

    CGGradientRef gradient = [self lineGradient];

    CGPoint points[9] = {
        CGPointMake(10.f, 25.f),
        CGPointMake(100.f, 100.f),
        CGPointMake(100.f, 150.f),
        CGPointMake(22.f, 300.f),
        CGPointMake(230.f, 400.f),
        CGPointMake(230.f, 200.f),
        CGPointMake(300.f, 200.f),
        CGPointMake(310.f, 160.f),
        CGPointMake(280.f, 100.f)
    };


    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        CGPoint start = points[i - 1];
        CGPoint end = points[i];
        CGFloat dy = end.y - start.y;
        CGFloat dx = end.x - start.x;
        CGFloat xOffset, yOffset;
        // Remember that, unlike Cartesian geometry, origin is in *upper* left!
        if (dx == 0) {
            // Vertical to start, gradient is horizontal
            xOffset = 0.5 * strokeWidth;
            yOffset = 0.f;
            if (dy < 0) {
                xOffset *= -1;
            }
        }
        else if (dy == 0) {
            // Horizontal to start, gradient is vertical
            xOffset = 0.f;
            yOffset = 0.5 * strokeWidth;
        }
        else {
            // Sloped
            CGFloat gradientSlope = - dx / dy;
            xOffset = 0.5 * strokeWidth / sqrt(1 + gradientSlope * gradientSlope);
            yOffset = 0.5 * strokeWidth / sqrt(1 + 1 / (gradientSlope * gradientSlope));
            if (dx < 0 && dy > 0) {
                yOffset *= -1;
            }
            else if (dx > 0 && dy < 0) {
                xOffset *= -1;
            }
            else if (dx < 0 && dy < 0) {
                yOffset *= -1;
                xOffset *= -1;
            }
            else {
            }
        }
        CGAffineTransform startTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-xOffset, yOffset);
        CGAffineTransform endTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xOffset, -yOffset);
        CGPoint gradientStart = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(start, startTransform);
        CGPoint gradientEnd = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(start, endTransform);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x, start.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x, end.y);
        CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context);
        CGContextClip(context);
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, 
                                    gradient, 
                                    gradientStart, 
                                    gradientEnd, 
                                    kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation | kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say they are drawing a CGPath around the original line, stroking the edges and gradient filling it. The ends are capped by adding a semi circle to the CGPath.

Would be a bit more work than simply drawing a single line and stroking it, but gives them full control over the style of the rendered path.

Comment: That sounds about right Chris, thanks. My problem is how to draw a gradient along a CGPath. Any ideas or code snippets you could share?

Comment: I don't know what the results will look like, but you can use `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath()` to retrieve an outline you can then fill with a gradient. This previous question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737973/on-osx-how-do-i-gradient-fill-a-path-stroke

Comment: After a bit of experimentation I can't find a way to easily get a gradient fill to follow a path, in the way that they are doing it. They might be breaking down the path and drawing a gradient fill for each segment separately.